# Angular scope value is not shown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I got a Service who returns some values from a database. Works well: ( The service is called Friends)

```
get: function(friendId) {
            // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
            promise2 = $http({
                url: "http://dev.tellthedj.de/db/getGutschein.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {"gutscheinId":friendId}
            }).then(function(response2) {
                // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
                // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
                return response2.data;
            });
            // Return the promise to the controller
            return promise2;
        }
```

This service is returning the right values for my purpose in correct json. Now I need to show this values in my view. Therefore I got this controller:

```
.controller('FriendDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Friends) {
    Friends.get($stateParams.friendId).then(function(b) {
        $scope.friend = b;
        console.log($scope.friend);
    });
})
```

This should be right it think! This is the HTML

```
<ion-view title="{{friend.name}}">
  <ion-content has-header="true" padding="true">
    {{friend.id}}
    {{friend.name}}
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The window is empty. No friend.id, no friend.name. Can´t find the mistake...

**UPDATE:**
Setting {{friend}} or {{friend | json}} is writing the complete returned json data in the view. When I try {{friend.name}} (which is inculded in that json object) there is no return.

The returned Object from the $http service ist exactly the same, like another Object from another Web-Service that works!

Comment: Did you define controller somewhere for view?

Comment: of course. .state('tab.friend-detail', {
      url: '/friend/:friendId',
      views: {
        'tab-friends': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/friend-detail.html',
          controller: 'FriendDetailCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

Comment: The console.log statement is also shown, so the controller is working

Comment: Could you try to output `{{friend | json}}` without ionic?

Comment: Try to add this `$scope.friend = {}` before the `Friends.get(` call

Comment: What is the `console.log` statement printing? Is it what you expect?

Comment: can you post the hole Page code with controller and app, ... and can you try to call "{{friend | json}}" outside the "ion-..."?

Comment: I updated question above

Comment: Can you provide an example of the returned JSON?

Comment: Also, what is the output of the console.log?

Comment: Third, have you put a console.log in your .then in your service so you can see what response2 contains?

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe it appears that the response from the server is not a JSON object but the string representation of it.
Try to add JSON.parse() to your code like this:

```
promise2 = $http({
                url: "http://dev.tellthedj.de/db/getGutschein.php",
                method: "POST",
                data: {"gutscheinId":friendId}
            }).then(function(response2) {
                // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
                // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
                return JSON.parse(response2.data); //<--- PARSE STRING TO OBJECT
            });
```